# attempt to perform arithmetic on field(a nil value)

Tags: lua, love2d

I have a player object that adds a bullet to ListOfBullets

```
function Player:keyPressed(key)
    --If the spacebar is pressed
    if key == "space" then
        --Put a new instance of Bullet inside listOfBullets.
        table.insert(ListOfBullets, Bullet(self.x, self.y, self.state))
    end
end
```

main updates and draws each bullet in the list here

```
function love.update(dt)
    Player:update(dt)
    Enemy:update(dt)
    for i,v in ipairs(ListOfBullets) do
        v:update(dt)
       
    
    end
end
```

Bullet looks like this and implemented with this:https://github.com/rxi/classic

```
function Bullet:new(xpos,ypos,state)
    self.x = xpos
    self.y = ypos
    self.state = state
    self.speed = 700
    self.r = 10

end

function Bullet:update(dt)
    self.y = self.y + self.speed*dt
    
end

function Bullet:draw()
    love.graphics.setColor(0,0,0,1)
    love.graphics.circle("fill", self.x, self.y, self.r)
end
```

beginner to programming, in general, was following a tutorial on simple game design when I had this problem
for some reason y and x are nil and I can't figure out why, where am I going wrong with this

Comment: Please post complete error message and all relevant code (for example how you declare Bullet, if it just table, or you for example set some metatable to it).

Comment: Short answer: `Bullet:new` implemented wrongly. Hint: `self` refers to the class, not to the instance being created.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, how you declare Bullet (as it has to have metatable as you call it like function)

I suppose, that in Bullet:new function, you want to create a new bullet as new object (or table). But you are not returning anything - you are just assigning values to self. This wouldn't work, as you want to return a new bullet. So correct code would be something like:

```lua
local Bullet = {}
Bullet.__index = Bullet

function Bullet.new(xpos, ypos, state) -- also notice, that for new, you use . and not : as you are only creating new object, if you would use self, you would assign values to Bullet, not you newly created bullet
    local self = setmetatable({}, Bullet) -- you can also declare x, y, ... in this table too
    self.x = xpos
    self.y = ypos
    self.state = state
    self.speed = 700
    self.r = 10

    return bullet
end

-- and your other functions
function Bullet:update(dt)
    self.y = self.y + self.speed*dt
end
```

And then, you can use it like you use it

```lua
local myBullet = Bullet.new(1, 2, 'test')
myBullet:update(dt)
```

For more information about Object Oriented Programming in Lua, see [lua-users wiki](https://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectOrientationTutorial)